# Journal of the Matter Modeling Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, answers, thanks

Some of our answers (or questions) here rise to the level of a "mini-publication" for their high-standards in original research or educational/pedagocial value. This is an incomplete list of such answers.

Comment: I think that an open book written collaboratively could be better

Answer (score 7):

##### Answers:

- **Frank Jensen** (2020) [Approximate equivalence table between Pople's basis sets and Jensen's DFT optimized polarization consistent basis sets (pcseg-n)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/361/5).
- **Etienne Palos** (2020) [Where is the extended Hückel method (EHM) still used today?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/86/5).
- **ProfM** (2020) [What is band inversion and how to recognize it in band structure?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1546/7)
- **Phil Hasnip** (2022) [The relationship between average eigenvalue and convergence performance in VASP?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/8809/5).
- **Phil Hasnip** (2022) [Number of k-points vs number of electrons: which is more significant in terms of computational cost for plane-wave calculations?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/9569/5)
- **Phil Hasnip** (2022) [Perovskite formation energy from precursors](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10057/5)
- **Phil Hasnip** (2022) [How to perform calc to ecutwfc and ecutrho in Quantum ESPRESSO](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10074/5)

Answer (score 1):

##### Citations:

- "**B. Kelly** (2022) [How to add molecules to a specific location in periodic box using gromacs?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/8892/5)" was cited in a thesis. See here: [How to convert mattermodeling stackexchange answer citation to ACS format?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/343/5)